# CRM - Disable clipboard functions on the NON-editable grid on entity home page grid

Tags: dynamics-crm, powerapps-modeldriven, webresource

My requirement is to restrict copy/paste of available data from the non-editable grid from the CRM entity home page.

I know that we can achieve it through JavaScript but certainly not sure how to apply that globally.

Can anyone help here?

```
// Disable copy and paste events
document.addEventListener('copy', function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
});

document.addEventListener('paste', function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
});
```